# Weird behaviour in laravel eloquent pluck with raw concat

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I had the following ORM which was working

```
$timezones = DB::table('timezones')->pluck(DB::Raw('concat_ws(" ",label,name) as name'), 'id');
```

I converted it to

```
$timezones = Timezone::pluck(DB::Raw('concat_ws(" ",label,name) as name'), 'id');
```

and got the error like below

```
ErrorException in Str.php line 432:
Illegal offset type in isset or empty
```

Model is pretty simple like below

```
class Timezone extends Model
{

     protected $table = 'timezones';
     protected $connection = 'mysql';

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, Your raw query inside pluck refers to an object. So, when to try to get an element with index as object error has been displayed.

You should change your query to something like this:

```
$timezones = Timezone::select(DB::Raw('concat_ws(" ",label,name) as name'), 'id')->pluck('name','id');
```

This will work. Hope it will help

Comment: Glad to see it helped you

Comment: A quick reference: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck It shows: Collection pluck(string $column, string|null $key = null) So $column has to be a string and not an object. Good job in catching that Sagar.

Comment: @RaviGehlot Thank you I have this same problem few days ago

Answer (score 1):

One other way to achieve the same results without having to use DB::raw and MySQL's concat_ws is to use Laravel's Accessors. So for example:

On your Timezone model, create an accessor method like this:

```
public function getLabelAttribute($value)
{
    return $value . ' ' . $this->name;
}
```

Then you can retrieve that by doing this:

```
$timezone = Timezone::first();
$timezone->label;
```

Comment: This one  is better when we have too complicated  stuffs on raw sql